# Dockerize a monorepo - node, react, nestjs and workspaces

Tags: reactjs, docker, nestjs, monorepo

I'm just starting to get into docker and I want to setup a monorepo with workspaces which I can use as a base for new development ideas of mine.

So I already setup a working monorepo with node, react, nestjs and workspaces, but now I want to dockerize that thing.

Now my problem is that I've tried so many times and still can't get it to work.
I want my host filesystem to be able to write to files in the container and edit them and whenever that happens I wan't to reload the app in which the file is located (so for react with webpack and nestjs with --watch)

I don't want that the container is able to write to my host filesystem, because then it'll create folders like "node_modules" for example and those will have the permission of root, which is not my user I'm using on the filesystem.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
root/
  docker/             // Dockerfiles are in here
    client/
    nginx/
    server/
  packages/           // My apps are in here
    client/           // react client
    server/           // nestjs backend
.dockerignore
docker-compose.yml
Makefile
package.json
package-lock.json
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - mono-node-modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./:/usr/src/app

  server:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/server/Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - mono-node-modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./:/usr/src/app

  client:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/client/Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - mono-node-modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./:/usr/src/app

volumes:
  mono-node-modules:
```

My client Dockerfile looks like this for example:

```yaml
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./packages/client/package.json .
COPY ./packages/client/package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

COPY ./packages/client .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:client" ]
```

But as I said above I don't really know how to get it all to work and am a bit stuck here after hours of working on it and watching tutorials.

Does anybody have some tips for me or can show me an example docker-compose.yml or Dockerfiles that would help me? :)

Comment: Take a look at my small monorepo I did some time ago - it has React front end and Apollo GraphQL backend and probably does what you want to achieve. :) https://github.com/mjgasior/cracker-app/tree/master

Comment: Is each of the `packages/*` directories self-contained; does each contain its own `package{,-lock}.json` files?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, each of the packages/* directories is self-contained and does contain its own package.json and package-lock.json. They share dependencies with the root package.json tho.